# cannot connect with datasource in grails project

Tags: grails

I have created a `Grails 3.3.8` project. The datasource (Oracle) configuration is successfully done in the `application.yml` file. But when I am using the datasource in my groovy class I am facing the following error:

```
Caused by GroovyRuntimeException: Ambiguous method overloading for method groovy.sql.Sql#<init>.
Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [null] due to overlapping prototypes between:
    [interface java.sql.Connection]
    [interface javax.sql.DataSource]
```

My code is :

```
package DATABASE_CONF
import groovy.sql.Sql  
/**
 *
 * @author CESC
 */
public class dbconn {

    def dataSource

    public String showname2() {

        def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
        def namestr = ""

        sql.eachRow('select * from TEST_TB') {
            tp -> 
            namestr = namestr + "<br>" + tp.NAME
        }  

        sql.close()
        return namestr          
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your class can not resolve the `dataSource` property, hence a null and ambigous method overloading exception.

The reason for that might be that your class resides in `src` folder and does NOT take part in bean (auto-)wiring. There are several options to deal with the issue:

1. put your class under /grails-app/services`so it will get the`dataSource` injected automatically (recommended)
2. declare the `dataSource` as an argument of `showname2()` method and pass it explicitely upon each call.
3. add a wiring mechanizm to your class. I'm not an expert in Spring, but I think it is an annotation and some configuration tweaks.

Comment: I have created a service class under services folder. But same error coming.

Comment: package mis_gp2

import grails.gorm.transactions.Transactional
import groovy.sql.Sql

@Transactional
class AG_shownameService {

    def dataSource
  
    
    private List showname34()
    {
    def myList = []   
    def sql = new Sql(dataSource)    
    def namestr = ""
    sql.eachRow('select * from TEST_TB') {
         tp -> 
         //namestr = namestr + "<br>" + tp.NAME
         myList << tp.NAME
      }  
  
      sql.close()
      return myList
      
    }
}

Comment: Pls edit your original post and put that code there - it's really difficuilt to read like that. have you restarted your app after creating the service?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this exact same error message. What I found to work was manually injecting the dataSource bean like this:

```
class SomeClass {
 def dataSource = grails.util.Holders.applicationContext.getBean("dataSource")

 def myMethod {
      Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)
       //Enter a SQL query
   }
}
```